# Proof that $x^2$ is continuous by $x = x_0 +h$ definition

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

Let's first sketch the proof:

$$|f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)| = |(x_0 +h)^2 - x_0^2| = |h^2 + 2x_0h| \leq|h||h + 2x_0|...\text{Now  let's say that |h|$< \delta$ $...$}\\ |h||h + 2x_0|< |h||1 + 2x_0| < \epsilon \implies |h| < \frac{\epsilon}{1+2x_0}$$

So we got the value for delta and that is $\delta:=\min\{1,  \frac{\epsilon}{1+2x_0}\}$

Now the proof:

There exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|h| < \delta = \frac{\epsilon}{1+2x_0} \iff|h|\cdot (1+2x_0) \leq |h|\cdot|1 + 2x_0| > |h^2 + 2x_0h | = |(x_0 +h)^2-x_0| < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$

Comment: What about if $x_0=-\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: We wish to show that for every $\DeclareMathOperator{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that, for all $h$, if $|h|<\delta$, then $|(x+h)^2-x^2|<\epsilon$. Simplifying, we need $|2hx+h^2|<\epsilon$. Note that for $|h|<1$ we have $|h^2|<|h|$, and so $|2hx+h^2|\le|2hx|+|h^2|<|2hx|+|h|=|h|\left(|2x|+1\right)$. Since
$$
|h|\left(|2x|+1\right)<\epsilon \iff |h|<\frac{\epsilon}{|2x|+1} \, ,
$$
we can take
$$
\delta=\min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{|2x|+1}\right) \, .
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textit{Analytical proof}$

Function is continuous if:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$$

where $x_0 = \displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n.$

Let's do this step by step:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} x^2 &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n^2 \hspace{8mm} x_n^2 \hspace{2mm} \text{ is convergent sequence, we can put limit inside } ^2 \\
&= \left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n\right)^2 = x_0^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}

We find out that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow x0} f(x) = f(x_0)$, it means that function is continuous in $x=x_0$. Also we can do this using right and left limits.

$\textit{Proof by definition}$

Using $\varepsilon - \delta$ (Cauchy definition) definition:

$$\epsilon > 0,\hspace{2mm} \delta > 0,\hspace{2mm} |x-x_0|<\delta\hspace{2mm} \Rightarrow\hspace{2mm} |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$$

Let's do this:
$$|x-x_0| < \delta$$

Trying to rewrite second inequality:
$$|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow |x^2 - x_0^2| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow |x-x_0||x+x_0| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow |x-x0||x-x_0+2x_0| < \delta (\delta + 2|x_0|) < \epsilon$$

We know that $0 < \delta < 1$, this inequality helps us to rewrite previous inequality:
$$\delta (\delta + 2|x_0|) < \delta (1 + 2|x_0|) < \varepsilon$$

Finally:
$$\delta < \frac{\varepsilon}{1 + 2|x_0|}$$
$$\delta < \min\left\{1, \frac{\varepsilon}{1 + 2|x_0|}\right\}$$

$\textit{Proof in terms of increment of argument}$

Definition:
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \Delta f = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) = 0$$

Or we can rewrite as:
$$\epsilon > 0,\hspace{2mm} \delta > 0,\hspace{2mm} |h-0|<\delta\hspace{2mm} \Rightarrow\hspace{2mm} |f(x_0+h) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$$

The proof is analogical to yours or to my previous proof for Cauchy definition.